# display/hide a div conditionally onclick of a link in another div

Tags: javascript, css, html, nav, navigationbar

I am trying to have two navigation bars (2 div tags). One is displayed by default (nav_bar) and the other is displayed when one of the links (in default nav bar) is clicked. I want to hide the other nav bar (IT_Spend_Nav) by default. Here is my code. The other nav bar is hidden by default but when I try to click links in the other (IT Spend) nav bar, the nav bar disappears. Here's a part of my code. I want the other nav bar to be displayed as long as the user wants to be in that particular section (IT Spend). Please help. Thanks.

```
<div id="nav_bar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_Nav');">IT Spend</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Assessment_Nav');">Assessments</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Information_Nav');">Information</a></li>
</ul>
</div>     

<div id = "IT_Spend_Nav" hidden="true">
<ul> 
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">2012</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">2013</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">2014</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">2015</a></li>
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">IT Spend Growth Trend</a>   </li>   
<li><a href="#none" onclick="showdiv('IT_Spend_2012');">IT OPEX/CAPEX Summary</a></li>  
</ul>
</div> 

javascript

var _targetdiv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
if(_targetdiv)
    _targetdiv.style.display = 'none';
_targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);
           _targetdiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with it?

Comment: Looks like `targetDiv.style.display` is always set to `block`. You've to set `targetDiv` to refer to element from the start, then check the value of `display` instead of `targetDiv` itself.

Comment: thanks for you reply Muzsi. But I am not good at coding. The javascript code that you see above was copied from stackoverflow. Can you let me know how.

Comment: I made a fiddle using your example code - http://jsfiddle.net/pRNZ3/

It seems to work fine (take a look), where is your JavaScript code placed within the HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRNZ3/1/) so that the menus no longer disappear

The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var _menus = [{
    id : 'nav_bar',
    hidden: false
}, {
    id : 'IT_Spend_Nav',
    hidden : true
}];

function reset() {
    for (var i=0; i< _menus.length; i++) {
       var elem = _menus[i],
           currDiv = document.getElementById(elem.id);
       currDiv.hidden = elem.hidden;
    }
}

function showdiv(id, parentId) {
    var _targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);
    var _parentDiv = document.getElementById(parentId);

    // reset to default state
    reset();

    // show current menu. make sure parent is also visible
    if (_parentDiv) {
        _parentDiv.hidden = false;
    }

    if (_targetdiv) {
        _targetdiv.hidden = false;   
    }
}
```

I simply made that all menus reset to their default states when a button is clicked, after which we show only the relevant divs (the current div and its parent div, in case you have nested menus).

In the html the only thing I changed was to add also the parent div id when calling the showdiv function on all button clicks (for example `showdiv('IT_Spend_2012', 'IT_Spend_Nav');` for the first button)